# Check for pair in an array with a given sum

Tags: c#

I was working on this problem in c#,

Write a program that finds in given array of integers a sequence of given sum S (if present).

here is how it should work

Input:  {4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4}, S = 11
Output: "First Sequence: {4, 2, 5}, 4 + 2 + 5 = 11", "Second Sequence: {2, 5, 4}, 2 + 5 + 4 = 11"

But what I get as output is the correct sum, I tried for other numbers as well

Output from console directly:
11
11

My code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4 };
        int S = 11;
        int p = 0;
        int[] sumSeq = { };


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            p = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {  
                if (arr[j]!=arr[i])
                {
                    p += arr[j] + arr[i];
                    if (p == S)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(p);
                        break;
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
       
       
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result you want to get? You could simply explain it with an real example.

Comment: Do you want pairs (which implies _two elements_ summing to `S`) or any number of elements? Please include your expected output and actual output

Comment: You should extract the bulk of the logic into a function (e.g. `FindSums(int[] array, int sum)` and describe for a given set of inputs, what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Are you looking for pair? as your code don't indicate that

Comment: If you don't know what  is being asked from you ("find a subarray / pairing", "what this subarray is") there is not much we can help here - to be able to get an answer on SO *you* should be able to explain exactly you trying to achieve. Ask your teacher what exactly they are looking for and [edit] the question to clarify. (Again "pair" and "subarray" are different already, and sub-arrays can be either sequntial or with holes...)

Comment: I edited the code, should be fine now and also the question, I think it is clearer. I believe @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @zaggler It is just for integers, not counting float/doubles sorry for the misunderstanding